# z-index works just in FF

Tags: firefox, z-index

I have a small problem with z-index on my site http://süperb.de.

In the header there are four links in a div with z-index:99. Under them there is the logo with z-index:1.

My problem: the links are just completable clickable in FF. In Chrome and Safari the z-index doesn't work and they are not completable clickable.

Help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that chrome does not calculate the width and height of the A tag properly, try setting `{ display: block; }` on the surrounding `a` tag, if that doesn't work, you might have to set a width and height on the a tag aswell.